# FLash Builder 4 Debug Application using the same html file

Tags: apache-flex, debugging, flash-builder

I have an html file which I want to use every time I debug my flex application. I don't want an new html file to be generated every time. How can I do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why did you want to do this?  Was it to pass custom flashvar values in during debugging?  I have this idea and was wondering if it was feasible.

Comment: Yes it is in order to pass custom flashvars to simulate server responses cause I have a lot of user action from emails (activate,confirm etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set compiler settings to turn off html generation and in debug settings you can customize the URL for debugging.

Comment: I've turned off the html generation but how can I customize the url for debugging?